# How to mount Google Drive as a network share in macOS for free?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, google-drive

I would like to note that this was written in 2016.
I own a MacBook Air with only 128GB of SSD on it. Luckily, my Google Apps' provider has unlimited Google Drive storage. Is there a way to mount Google Drive as a network share for free, meaning no paid software or shareware? Google Drive FUSE is deprecated, syngYa gives me a quota error and does not work properly in Finder, and DAV-pocket gives me an error 500 when trying to sign up.

Anyone know a solution?
Please note - this does not mean the Google Drive application for Mac, as that stores it in a folder on the SSD, taking up space.

Comment: you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but my search for this option on Mac led me here.

I've been using [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) for a few years now in Linux. It looks like it's still buggy on MacOs. While not quite as good performance-wise for Google Drive (at least not in Linux), there is also the option of [rclone](https://rclone.org/). Both are command line tools, and in your use case both will rely on FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) to mount a remote drive as if it were a local directory (but only using local storage space for caching). With either option, you'll also likely need to install [OSXFuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/).

The pros of rclone are:

1. Supports several cloud services, like OneDrive, Dropbox, Mega, and even Amazon S3 (and compatible) storage.
2. Looks like it actually works on MacOS right now. Download it here: https://rclone.org/downloads/
3. GUI frontends are available for rclone (varying in quality) for multiple supported OS, but I can't say whether Mac options allow for the `rclone mount` command that you'll need for mounting Google Drive in FUSE rather than syncing the whole folder.